# Passing list or array (as parameter) in Django View

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

How to use the passed value (list/array) in Django View? 
I have tried something like this:

```
def to_csv(request):
    g_data = request.GET.getlist('json_data')
    g_header = request.GET.get('header')
    g_info = request.GET.get('info')
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

    list_header = [[g_info, '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                   ['Municipality', 'Barangay', 'Total Number of Structures', 'Total Not Affected', 'Total Affected',
                    'Low', 'Medium', 'High', 'Total Affected %']]
    disclaimer = [
        'Disclaimer: The information....',
        '', '', '', '', '', '']

    for val in g_data:
        perc = (val[4] / float(val[2])) * 100
        st_perc = str(round(perc, 2))
        val.append(st_perc)
        list_header.append(val)

    list_header.append(disclaimer)

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerows(list_header)
    return response
```

and in my JavaScript code using AJAX:

```
function to_csv(json_data, header, info){
 $.ajax({
    url: "/to_csv/",
    headers: {
    Accept : "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Type": "text/csv; charset=utf-8"
    },
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        'json_data': json_data,
        'header': header,
        'info':info
    },
```

The problem is, it does not get the passed data (*g_data*)

Answer (score 1):

It seems a waste of a round trip to send your data to the server and ask it to create a CSV when you can quite easily do that in the javascript itself. Less load on the server, faster response.

Assuming your link is like

```
<a href="" id="download_link">Download CSV</a>
```

Then

```
function to_csv(json_data, header, info){
    var s = "data:text/csv,"
    for (var key in json_data) {
        if (json_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            s += json_data[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using json.loads:

```
g_data = json.loads(request.GET.get('json_data'))
```